# Search filter in Container Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm trying to implement a search filter in my Container which contains a set of buttons.

Here's my code:

```
public void listMenu() {

    Dialog loading = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();
    loading.show();

    final Form listMenu = new Form("List Menu");
    listMenu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Container list = new Container();
    list.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    list.removeAll();

    Button back = new Button("Back to Main Menu");

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("mylist");
    query.whereExists("Title");

    List<ParseObject> results = null;

    try {

        Button btn = null;
        results = query.find();

        if(!results.isEmpty()) {
        int index = 0;
        int size = results.size();
        for(;index < size;++index) {
            list.add(btn = new Button(results.get(index).getString("Title")));
            addListener(btn);
        }
        }

    } catch (com.parse4cn1.ParseException e) {

        Dialog.show("Err", "Server is not responding.", "OK", null);
    }

    listMenu.add(list);
    listMenu.add(back);
    listMenu.show();
    loading.dispose();

    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
        {
            new StateMachine("/theme");
        }
    });
}
```

This code basically is querying data from the Database then setting its results into buttons then added to a Container. My question is how to implement a search filter to my Container? I've seen `FilterProxyListModel<T>` but not sure if `ListModel<T>` is compatible with `Container`. I'd appreciate to see an example of search filter implementation in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FilterProxyListModel` is for `List` which we don't recommend anymore. There is a full sample of searching a container [here](http://codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html). It uses `MultiButton` but using `Button` would work just as well:

```
hi.getToolbar().addSearchCommand(e -> {
    String text = (String)e.getSource();
    if(text == null || text.length() == 0) {
        // clear search
        for(Component cmp : hi.getContentPane()) {
            cmp.setHidden(false);
            cmp.setVisible(true);
        }
        hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(150);
    } else {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        for(Component cmp : hi.getContentPane()) {
            Button mb = (Button)cmp;
            String line1 = mb.getText();
            boolean show = line1 != null && line1.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
            mb.setHidden(!show);
            mb.setVisible(show);
        }
        hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(150);
    }
}, 4);
```

Comment: Added to my code but when I try to do my first search I got this: Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException - com.codename1.ui.Container cannot be cast to com.codename1.ui.Button

Comment: In your case you need to use `list` and not the content pane like the sample code did

Comment: Thanks a lot, fixed it by changing `hi.getContentPane()` to my `Container` then everything is working as intended.